# Divide an amout equally beteen no of user

Tags: php, math

I want to distribute an amount among some users equally.If amount is not divisible equally then all other member will get equal amount expect the last member who will get rest of the money.Below is what i have tried

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
$noOfTime = $_POST['no_of_time'];
$perHead = ceil($number / $noOfTime);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $noOfTime; $i++) {
    if ($i == $noOfTime) {
        echo $perHead * $noOfTime - $number;
    } else {
        echo $perHead;
    }
}
```

Here if number is 7 and member are 4 the first 3 member will the 2 and the last will get 1. Like 2,2,2,1.

But this logic seems to be not working for all cases.

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are looking get your homework done today,

Comment: take number as 9 your logic fails so dont use ceil use floor repeat logic till u get amount to be distributed 0 try for 9 u will crack it

Comment: Do you have an example on what case this doesn't work? You're saying that it won't, but not providing an example.

Comment: Just as a hint, there's a term used in programming called the module (%) which gives you the remainer of a certain division. You'd probably want to know that's available for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should help you.

```
$no =       22;
$users =    8;

// count from 0 to $users number
for ($i=0;$i<$users;$i++)
    // if the counting reaches the last user AND $no/$users rests other than 0...
    if ($i == $users-1 && $no % $users !== 0) {
        // do the math rounding fractions down with floor and add the rest!
        echo floor($no / $users) + ($no % $users);
    } else {
        // else, just do the math and round it down.
        echo floor($no / $users)." ";
    }
```

OUTPUTS:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 8
```

**EDIT**: I nested an `if` verification so the logic won't fail even if `users` are 1 or 2. And since it received more upvotes, I commented the code to make it more clear.

Comment: 3 users and 4 disributions?

Comment: but now also more distibutions the correct answer for above will be 7,7,8

Comment: No it won't, because there are 8 users in my example, not 3.